# Query Parse server and local datastore at the same time

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to create a `PFQuery` in which the response for the query is stored both on the server and in the local datastore. I would like to create one query with a constraint (`query.whereKey()`) and it will first look to see if the response is stored on the device, and if not, it will then query the server.

For example, I am loading a list of posts. The app stores a group of Users that the current user is following. For the posts posted by the users stored on the device, I would like to load the users details (like their profile picture and username) from the datastore, not the server. However if the post is posted by a user not stored on the device, it would query the server. I can only imagine this doing with 2 different queries but I would prefer to do it in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the following in my own project and am posting it in case anybody is looking for a complete answer.

The parameters are as follows:

1. `query`: The `PFQuery` that you would like to perform the query on.
2. `queryBoth`: A `Bool` value of whether or not you would like to query the Parse server if there is data returned from the local data store. `true` will query both, and `false` will only query the server if nothing is returned from the local data store.
3. `toCallUponCompletion`: A closure (function) that will be called when a response is received from either the server, local data store, or both. The function should accept an array of `PFObjects` and return nothing. An implementation of this function will be shown below the following function.

The function:

```
func findObjectsInBackgroundFromLocalDataStoreIfPossible (query: PFQuery, queryBoth: Bool, toCallUponCompletion: ([PFObject]) -> ()){
    var response = [PFObject]()

    let queryCopy = query.copy() as! PFQuery
    queryCopy.fromLocalDatastore()
    queryCopy.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            if objects?.count == 0{
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                     (objects2: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil{
                        response = objects2 as! [PFObject]
                        toCallUponCompletion(response)
                    }
                }
            }
            else if queryBoth{
                response = objects as! [PFObject]
                var responseObjectIds = [String]()
                for x in response{
                    responseObjectIds.append(x.objectId)
                }
                query.whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: responseObjectIds)
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                    (objects2: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil{
                        response += objects2 as! [PFObject]
                        toCallUponCompletion(response)
                    }
                    else{
                        toCallUponCompletion(response)
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                response = objects as! [PFObject]
                toCallUponCompletion(response)
            }
        }
        else{
            println("Error being called in 'findObjectInBackgroundFromLocalDataStoreIfPossible' Error is: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Closure implementation:

```
func storeResponse (response: [PFObject]){
    println(response)
}
```

---

To achieve the same functionality as the above function but with multiple `PFQueries` use the following:

The parameters differ as follows:

1. `queries`: This is the array of `PFQueries` that you would like to perform the query on. The order is important.
2. `toCallUponCompletion`: This closure instead takes a dictionary with `Int` keys and `PFObject` values as a parameter and returns nothing. The reason for this is because when the queries are sent, they may not complete and come back in the same order. So the key for every key- value pair in the dictionary is the order it was sent and thus the response could be used without knowing the actual contents of the response. Again, refer to the implementation of the function closure following the function.

The function:

```
func findObjectsInBackgroundFromMultipleQueriesFromLocalDataStoreIfPossible (queries: [PFQuery], queryBoth: Bool, toCallUponCompletion: ([Int: [PFObject]]) -> ()){
    var responses = [Int: [PFObject]]()
    for query in queries{
        var response = [PFObject]()
        let queryCopy = query.copy() as! PFQuery
        queryCopy.fromLocalDatastore()
        queryCopy.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil{
                if objects?.count == 0{
                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                        (objects2: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil{
                            response = objects2 as! [PFObject]
                            responses[find(queries, query)!] = response  
                            if responses.count == queries.count{
                                toCallUponCompletion(responses)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if queryBoth{
                    response = objects as! [PFObject]
                    var ids = [String]()
                    for x in response{
                        ids.append(x.objectId)
                    }
                    query.whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: ids)
                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                        (objects2: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil{
                            response += objects2 as! [PFObject]
                            responses[find(queries, query)!] = response
                            if responses.count == queries.count{
                                toCallUponCompletion(responses)
                            }
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 else{
                     response = objects as! [PFObject]
                     responses[find(queries, query)!] = response
                     if responses.count == queries.count{
                         toCallUponCompletion(responses)
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Closure implementation:

```
func storeResponses (responses: [Int: PFObject]){
    println("The response to the first query is: \(responses[0])")
    println("The response to the second query is: \(responses[1])")
    println("The response to the third query is: \(responses[2])")
}
```

Any suggestions for edits are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Parse has a `fromLocalDatastore` method for `PFQuery` but I am not aware of a `notFromLocalDatastore` method... The only thing I can think of is making a method that will return a newly created query, then you can call:

```
userQuery().fromLocalDatastore().getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { localR in
    if let user = localR {
        //use the user
    } else {
        userQuery().getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { serverR
            if let user = serverR {
                //user the user
            } else {
                //not even on server - handle somehow...
            }
        }
    }
}
```